# How to set link photo to button image background swift?

Tags: json, swift

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage?
let link = "https://shopme.uz/upload/resize_cache/iblock/dee/500_500_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/deecd89d7c312917dd568ea62218da82.jpg"
let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
button.setImage(link, forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work. 
Actually I have JSON, and I getting image link from this. I should add this images to button background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download Url image first

```
if let getUrl = url {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: getUrl)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let getData = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: getData)
                        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                    } else {   
                       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "default.png"), forState: .Normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

With extension to reuse this code

```
extension UIButton {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use this extension

```
if let getURL = URL(string: "your link") {
           button.load(url: getURL)
        }
```

With cache Support

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
extension UIButton {

    func setImageFromLink(_ URLString: String, placeHolder: UIImage? = nil , cache:Bool = false) {
        if cache {
            loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(URLString, placeHolder: placeHolder)
        } else {
            if let getUrl = URL(string: URLString) {
                load(getUrl, placeHolder: placeHolder)
            }
        }
    }


   private func load(_ url: URL, placeHolder: UIImage? = nil ) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }






      private  func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(_ URLString: String, placeHolder: UIImage?) {

            self.imageView?.image = nil
            if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: NSString(string: URLString)) {
                 self.setImage(cachedImage, for: .normal)
                return
            }

            if let url = URL(string: URLString) {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    //print("RESPONSE FROM API: \(response)")
                    if error != nil {
                        print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(String(describing: error))")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                             self?.setImage(placeHolder, for: .normal)
                        }
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        if let data = data {
                            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: URLString))

                                 self?.setImage(downloadedImage, for: .normal)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        }

}
```

How to use with **cache Support**

```
 butt.setImageFromLink("url string", placeHolder: UIImage(named: "your default image"), cache: true)

        //or without cache

  butt.setImageFromLink("url string")

       //or without cache and Placeholder Image

  butt.setImageFromLink("url string", placeHolder: UIImage(named: "your default image"))
```

Comment: how can I download image can you please share code?

Comment: better is to use extension ... i write how to use that as well ... so that it become easy to use

Comment: I need little help with adding actions to dynamic buttons. How can I contact with you?